# Powershell split

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a problem with `LastWriteTime`. 
I need to split this value:

```
09/26/2014 10:14:34 09/26/2014 08:09:59
```

I tried this:

```
foreach ($line in $data){write-host $line}.
```

But I need to write it to `$date1` and `$date2`.

This is the code I use:

```
$Folder = Get-ChildItem "\\SERVER-14\data$\backup" -Exclude $ExcludeFolders -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select Name, LastWriteTime -first 2
$LastFolderName = $Folder.Name
$LastFolderTime = $Folder.LastWriteTime
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? I'm guessing you're trying to get the last write time of more than one file and trying to split each time into it's variable

Comment: Yes, I updatet my post.

Comment: What do you want to do with the Split date? Export that array to variables? If you want specific parts of it it would be a `[DateTime]` object you could manipulate

Comment: I want to write it to variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know you're always getting 2 objects as specified by `-first 2` in your `Select-Object`, you can directly reference them:

```
$date1 = $folder[0].lastWriteTime
$date2 = $folder[1].lastWriteTime
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = "09/26/2014 10:14:34 09/26/2014 08:09:59"

$data = $value.Split(' ')
# $data contains 4 values --> date, time, date, time
#i set up some variables
$date = $true;
$savedDate = "";

# Here we process the $data
$data |
    # For each in powershell =  %  
    %{
          #every odd line ( if $date is true),  we save the date value
          if($date){$date=$false;$savedDate=$_} 
          # every even line (if $date is false), we stick together the date and time
          else{$date=$true;$savedDate+ " " + $_;}
    }
```

Very "straight forward" solution...(maybe not so simple, sorry)

Split on whitespace
Iterate over all the strings, 
each time you have a date and a time string following each other. 
Thus save the first one as the date, 
every second value contains the time,  put it together and continue with the next date...

Comment: Doesn't look so simple to me. Care to add a bit more of an explanation?

Comment: I'm sorry. But it doesn't look simple to me. I just started with powershell.

Comment: I can't make it more clear then this, I think, I hope it's usefull

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is assign the first and second last write time to variables then append this to your script:

```
$date1 = $Folder[0].LastWriteTime
$date2 = $Folder[1].LastWriteTime
```

But you won't always know if the folder contains two items. By right you should be doing all the work for each item inside the foreach loop

```
foreach ($file in $Folder)
{
    #Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For splitting strings, you can use the Powershell -Split operator which uses a regex argument to control the split, or for simple cases like this you can use the dotnet [string] split method, which splits on an array of characters:

```
PS C:\> $line -split ' '
09/26/2014
10:14:34
09/26/2014
08:09:59

PS C:\> $line.split(' ')
09/26/2014
10:14:34
09/26/2014
08:09:59
```

Either way, you're going to get an array of the split elements.  Then you can selectively assign those to variables using array slicing:

```
PS C:\> $date1,$date2 = ($line -split ' ')[0,2]
PS C:\> $date1
09/26/2014
PS C:\> $date2
09/26/2014

PS C:\> $date1,$date2 = $line.split(' ')[0,2]
PS C:\> $date1
09/26/2014
PS C:\> $date2
09/26/2014
```

See:

[about_split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

[string methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)